# How can I solve Ubuntu 16.04 render problem Nvidia GeForce GTX 950M (rev a2)

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, suspend

I've tried Nouveau drivers, propietary drivers but without good results.
Some apps (for instance: Rocketchat) has a terrible rendering effect. Problem is worst after resume from suspend and have dual monitor, but it also occurs when using only laptop display (no dual monitor).

[image: Nvidia render problem]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGYCzW-HIOI